# Replace iteratively with things contained in array

Tags: awk, sed, replace

```
foo bar, foo bar, foo bar
foo bar
```

Given this beautiful poem, how could all the `bar` be replaced by `superman`, but each time with a different ending, contained in an array `(is super, is blazing fast, is marvelous, cawabanga)`

So the result would be :

```
foo superman is super, foo superman is blazing fast, foo superman is marvelous
foo superman cawabanga
```

I know it is possible to use a for/loop to do so, with sed. But is there a shorter, more beautiful solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this just with shell parameter expansion: It's really a one-liner

```
poem='foo bar, foo bar, foo bar
foo bar'
traits=( "is super" "is blazing fast" "is marvelous" "cawabanga" )

for trait in "${traits[@]}"; do poem=${poem/bar/"superman $trait"}; done

echo "$poem"
```

```
foo superman is super, foo superman is blazing fast, foo superman is marvelous
foo superman cawabanga
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried with simple array contents. you can apply the same logic for your question

```
$ declare -a var=(A B C D)

$ cat test.txt
foo bar, foo bar, foo bar
foo bar

$ awk -vArr="${var[*]}" 'BEGIN {split(Arr,awk_arr," ")}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/bar/){count++;$i=awk_arr[count]}}1' test.txt
foo A foo B foo C
foo D
```

Comment: That won't work with spaces in the array elements as in the question, though.

Comment: yes.. thats why i asked to implement this logic to OP